# Qt QMessageBox show buttons without color

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, qmessagebox

I've created an QMessageBox with customized buttons and they are showing up in gray as the image  bellow: [image: buttons in gray]

Running on Linux is fine! But on Raspberry it gives me in trouble.
The snippet of code that I wrote is the following:

```
#include "alertmessage.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QAbstractButton>
#include <QCoreApplication>
AlertMessage::AlertMessage(QMessageBox *parent): QMessageBox(parent)
{

    this->setFont(QFont("Roboto"));
    QFont font = this->font();
    font.setPointSize(26);
    this->setMaximumHeight(250);
    this->setModal(true);
    this->setMaximumWidth(this->minimumHeight());
    this->setWindowTitle(QString("Falha de conexão"));
    this->setChecker(new QCheckBox("Não mostrar essa menssagem novamente.", this));
    this->setText(QString("<p style='margin-bottom: 0cm; line-height: 100%; text-align: justify;'>"
"Houve uma falha de comunica&ccedil;&atilde;o com um ou mais sensores, isso poder&aacute; "
"afetar o desempenho do sistema.</p>"));
    this->setInformativeText(QString("<p style='margin-bottom: 0cm; line-height: 100%; text-align:justify;'><strong>Voc&ecirc;"
" quer continuar ou <span style='color: #ff0000;'>PARAR</span> a aplica&ccedil;&atilde;o?</strong></p>"));
    this->setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::No | QMessageBox::Yes);
    this->setButtonText(QMessageBox::No, QString("Parar").toUpper());
    this->setButtonText(QMessageBox::Yes, QString("Continuar"));
    QPalette okPalette = this->button(QMessageBox::Yes)->palette();
    QPalette noPalette = this->button(QMessageBox::No)->palette();
    okPalette.setColor(QPalette::Button, QColor(13, 71, 161));
    okPalette.setColor(QPalette::ButtonText, QColor(Qt::white));
    noPalette.setColor(QPalette::Button, QColor(127, 0, 0));
    noPalette.setColor(QPalette::ButtonText, QColor(Qt::white));
    this->button(QMessageBox::Yes)->setPalette(okPalette);
    this->button(QMessageBox::No)->setPalette(noPalette);
    this->setIcon(QMessageBox::Warning);
    this->setCheckBox(this->getChecker());
    this->connect(this->button(QMessageBox::Yes), SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(turnVisible()));
    this->connect(this->button(QMessageBox::No), SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(turnOFF()));


}
```

Comment: why you didn't handle the style of your message box with Stylesheet?

Comment: In my first attempt, I did It. I'm thinking if there is some relation with the Rasp "style" like Fusion, Windows style.

Comment: I mean to use `setStyleSheet` and define your Style, not style like Fusion, Windows-style

Comment: @Parisa.H.R, I got you.  I've already  tested it. But, I guess that I need to set some thing like this:  app.setStyle(QStyleFactory::keys()[1]);

Comment: Sorry, Do you test my answer and didn't work???? I add my screenshot too , it works for me.

Comment: @Parisa.H.R, your sugestion didn't work. But I solved it, each OS has some default styles and Qt will search for they to look more "native". Taking that into account I need to force my application to take a Style different from the raspberry standards styles.

Comment: @Parisa.H.R, your solution doesn't work, because you are running on Windows and Linux. I'm not using those  Operational Systems. How I said, I'm using Raspberry Pi OS.

Comment: Yes, I don't try raspberry pi. and it's strange thing because Qt is cross-platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, each OS has some default styles and Qt will search for they to look more "native". Taking that into account I need to force my application to take a Style different from the raspberry standards styles. The snipe of code that solved that:

```
QApplication  app(argc, argv);
qDebug() << QStyleFactory::keys(); //See available styles
app.setStyle("Fusion");
```

Answer (score 2):

I try it in Linux and windows, in both of them if you use `QPalette` they use your OS and System Styles, because of that if you want to have your style it's better to use **StyleSheet** .

another thing that I see in your code, if you put your code in a constructor it's not required to use `this`.

**I change something of the code and the result is this:**

```
    setFont(QFont("Roboto"));
    setAutoFillBackground(true);
    QFont font = this->font();
    font.setPointSize(26);
    setMaximumHeight(250);
    setModal(true);
    setMaximumWidth(minimumHeight());
    setWindowTitle(QString("Falha de conexão"));
    setChecker(new QCheckBox("Não mostrar essa menssagem novamente.", this));
    setText(QString("<p style='margin-bottom: 0cm; line-height: 100%; text-align: justify;'>"
"Houve uma falha de comunica&ccedil;&atilde;o com um ou mais sensores, isso poder&aacute; "
"afetar o desempenho do sistema.</p>"));
    this->setInformativeText(QString("<p style='margin-bottom: 0cm; line-height: 100%; text-align:justify;'><strong>Voc&ecirc;"
" quer continuar ou <span style='color: #ff0000;'>PARAR</span> a aplica&ccedil;&atilde;o?</strong></p>"));
    setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::No | QMessageBox::Yes);
    setButtonText(QMessageBox::No, QString("Parar").toUpper());
    setButtonText(QMessageBox::Yes, QString("Continuar"));
    button(QMessageBox::Yes)->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(13, 71, 161);color:white;"));
    button(QMessageBox::No)->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(127, 0, 0);color:white;"));
    setIcon(QMessageBox::Warning);
    setCheckBox(getChecker());
    connect(this->button(QMessageBox::Yes), SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(turnVisible()));
    connect(this->button(QMessageBox::No), SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(turnOFF()));
```

[image]